# Java Script eval() function belong to which Object ? Also execution context is passed on while invoking a eval() function

Tags: javascript, eval

My Questions regarding eval() function in JavaScript

1. To which object does eval() belong to ?
2. We know that all java script code gets a execution context . What execution context does eval() get ?Is it the global execution context ?
3. Why is eval() called an evil? Is there any case where eval() function can be a life saver ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

1. When you omit an object you actually call it on the window object. So its `window.eval`, but since its the default its the same as a global scope.
2. [Eval scope is tricky.](http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html) Basicly global scope.
3. Eval is very evil, you allow the user to execute arbitrary code. This is a very scary thing. Especially when it has user input you do not want to use eval. Any malicious user could  really give you a bad time.

Comment: @Niklas B . Why do you say that executing malicious code in the browser context is not dangerous ? Isn't the client machine at risk ?

Comment: I just found a useful case for eval() inside http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval under the head **What’s it good for?**

Comment: @Niklas B By "Javascript environment is user-controlled anyway" ,what did u actually mean ? Can you shed some light on it using examples if possible ?